# How can i publish my private dependency(npm package) with node modules to any private repository?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jenkins, npm

**Problem Statement**
That nodejs code has few private dependencies which are situated in different folder and relative paths of them in `package.json`. Lemme understand you better assume I want to build project A which have two B & C private dependencies and that dependencies are referred in Project A's package.json using folder relative path.

Before building A we need to build B and C also and here C is dependent on B. So before building C you also have to build B.

When C is building it requires B's `nodemodules`.

Now the bigger picture is that I want to automate this process using Jenkins and in that I can't use relative pathS. I need to host these dependencies on somewhere on the private repositories (like nexus artifacts repositories) But it that I don't have node-modules which is required in C.
I also want that to be published.

**What did I try**
Tried to publish packages on Sonatype nexus repository but it don't have node-modules in that package.

Comment: Why are you building b and c when building a? If you define a version of b and c in a, you should be installing those versions not building them or am I missing something? If you rebuild c or b - then you will may want to rebuild a, but not the other way around surely?

Comment: actually that part is necessary cause a is have dependency of node modules of b and c.